# Datatables : Using row to columns with php/mysql or else?

Tags: php, mysql, pivot-table, large-data

Got a large data set (500.000 entries) about products values.
Each data in a row like this :

```
product value
12345 red
12345 large
12345 portable
```

etc ..

I need to use datatable to display and filter data easily.

Troubles :

When i plan to use mysql, i have to use limit (10 for example) but limit considering a number of line not a number of products and number of values is not defined in advance.

```
SELECT pctv.id_produit,pctv.id_caracteristique_valeur 
FROM produit_to_caracteristique_valeur pctv 
LIMIT 10
```

I have tried pivot also but bad performance on large data sets.

If i use PHP to push all in array and slice, got a 500 error (memory limit)

Any ideas to achieve this ?

Regards

Comment: What is your expected O/P.??

Comment: Expecting data in columns 12345 : red, large, portable, with limit to avoid performance issues

Answer (score 0):

How about the following?

```
SELECT
    pctv.id_produit,
    pctv.id_caracteristique_valeur
FROM
    produit_to_caracteristique_valeur pctv
WHERE
    pctv.id_produit in (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            id_produit
        FROM
            produit_to_caracteristique_valeur
        LIMIT
            10
    )
```